# How to clear "Storm the Sheep" on extreme in Defender's Quest?

Tags: defenders-quest

I've tried a couple of strategies with little success so far.

So far my strategy consists of:

- 1 non-upgrade warrior to kill the normal sheeps
- 2 knights for knockback, stun and general damage (upgraded as much as possible)
- 1 ice mage for the slow and freeze (sometimes upgrade to lvl 3)
- 3-4 archers (as much as I can summon with the available "points")
- Using the push back and frenzy spells from time to time although the push back doesn't seem to work.

I swap all the characters as the sheep moves along the way.

I also tried using a Dragon to "now" the sheep when below 19% HP but it didn't work.

So am I on the good path or am I missing something completely obvious.

The battle selection screen for reference:[image: Storm the Sheep battle selection screen]

and the battle map:[image: Storm the Sheep battle map screen]

Comment: this is so hard, slow and stuns doesn't seem to work

Comment: What's the average level of your troops at the time you're attempting this?

Comment: Last time I tried maybe 25.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found it pretty easy using all level 20 troops (with level 22 librarian), using some of the advice from previous answers. The sheep ate it just past 1/2 way.

The general strategy was to follow the sheep with 3 unboosted ice mages for the first 1/4 of the path to build up slow debuff duration, then ambush him near the 1st corner with inspired berserkers and archers while he's under bleed, light and slow debuffs.

**Party:**

- 3 Ice Mages - to build up slow effect before the ambush (-65% spd.).

  ### - Lvl.9 Chill. I also had Lvl.9 Freeze which is probably useless, so most likely Lvl.10 mages would be just as good.
- 6 Archers

  - 1 to apply bleed debuff (+89% dmg.). (Lvl.9 Deep Shot & at least Lvl.1 Rapid Shot)

    ### - 5 to do damage. (Lvl.9 Rapid Shot and Lvl.9 Sharp Shooter)
- ~3 Berserkers - to do damage. Perhaps these are not needed.

  ### - Lvl.9 Flurry and Lvl.9 Madness.
- 4 or more Healers - to Inspire other troops & apply light debuff. I had 6, but 4 would be plenty I think.

  - Lvl.9 Inspire, Lvl.1 in all other skills. Inspired troops do +34% damage. I'm not sure if the light debuff increases (doubles?) damage taken or not, but the icon shows on the sheep so perhaps it does.

**Equipment:**

Everyone was equipped with weapons and armor bought at the dragon city/lair nearby, except one of the archers who had slightly better Captain's Warbow, rewarded from one of the earlier battles.

**What I did:**

1. Put someone to kill the weak sheep at the other spawn. (I used an unboosted berserker, but anyone would do I think, so long as it's not a dragon who might cancel the slow effect.)
2. Put 3 ice mages at start and follow the sheep with them up to about the 1st corner, without boosting them. By that point they'd built up enough slow effect to last the rest of the battle and I had enough psi to start following with berserkers instead. You can see if the slow effect has worn off by checking if the sheeps speed has gone back above 0.03.
3. Start setting up the ambush near the 1st corner. I set up Archers and Berserkers first, then Healers last, though perhaps setting up healers 2nd might be better. Anyhow, the troops were positioned as follows:

   - 1st row (adjacent to path): 3 Berserkers, fully boosted (move with the sheep).
   - 2nd Row: Healers, fully boosted (as many as you can get in range of the sheep and the troops they will inspire). Note: it seems they only cast Zeal (Inspire) when the sheep is in range, so you've got to keep an eye on them to make sure they're not slacking off.
   - 3rd and 4th rows: Archers, fully boosted, preferably within the range of a few healers. Bleed archer was the priority at the beginning (+89% dmg), then less so later when sheep had built up bleed debuff.
4. Keep moving everyone to keep them busy and inspired. By the time the sheep got to the 2nd corner I had enough psi to follow him with 3 berserkers as well as 2 healers beside them on the front row, other healers on 2nd row and keep all the archers in range, mostly near the healers. The sheep was practically finished by then anyway, so perhaps all that is required is Lvl.9 slow, Lvl.9 bleed and the the healers light debuff (if that actually has any effect), IDK.

[image]

**Other tips:**

- If you have a low level librarian, be careful not to recall more than a couple of fully boosted guys at once, otherwise the psi will max out when it returns and you'll lose some. It's best to use all the psi building/boosting before unpausing (if you pause to recall & move guys).
- As others mentioned, spamming Lvl.9 Frenzy spell helps too I think, though mostly I forgot.

Comment: This is a great, descriptive answer. Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: great answer, I got it to work, sheep is dead! Added screenshot. The key is the ice mages with fully boosted level 1 chill + the healers. I was not able to get it to work at all with just heavily boosted archers, even with most points in bleed.

Answer (score 5):

This level is annoying, but I got it with everyone under 30, mostly 26-29, but a few archers were recently added and leveled only up to 16-19. It's a tedious level having more to do with patience and care than anything else. You can't just go AFK and expect a dead sheep. But with a lot of re-summoning, I got the sheep dead a little bit before it could round the bottom-right corner. This area is pretty good for a last burst of damage, since there aren't too many rocks stopping your whole party from getting Inspire from multiple healers. None of my equipment was significantly better than the stuff you buy in the last store; I haven't done the last few Extreme challenges yet, and it's not necessary.

I spent most of my scrap respecing my six archers as well as my two ice mages (only needed two). Luckily, I already had a few berserkers who had Flurry and Madness maxed, as these are quite indispensable in the main game anyway. The same goes for Healers with Zeal + Inspire.

- By now, you should have a good feel for how to place archers so that after a couple boosts, they'll cover as much of the track as possible while also getting Inspire boosts frequently. It can be finicky, but you don't have to be perfect, either.
- For archers, the useful upgrades are bleed, poison, crit, rapid shot, and range. Extra one-point investments in other attack skills such as Black Out The Sun aren't a waste, but armor pen, for example, is a waste. Only one archer needs poison, and only one archer needs bleed, probably not the same archer, unless it's a high-level one.
- Archers should typically be boosted to 3 for Rapid Shot. Higher boosts are quite useful later when you have more Psi to work with, especially since they can sometimes work effectively for a fair amount of time without being resold. The best candidate for a boost is one who is high level, will be firing on the sheep for a long time, and will be getting Inspire from all three healers for the while. Eventually, all archers can be kept at 5 at all times.
- The one who applies bleed needn't be that high a level. All that is needed is perhaps bleed and range maxed.
- The one who applies poison should have crit and range so that a more effective poison is applied. From reading their blog, it sounds like only the most potent of any effect is ever active, with the durations stacking, so that one strong poison re-applied constantly is all that you could ever really need here. I'm not sure if crits up the poison potency, but I'd guess so and you may as well get the base damage from it anyway.
- The rest of the archers should just hit over and over. Rapid Shot should be maxed, as well as range and crit. Crit and Rapid Shot if you don't have the levels for more, because then you can just deploy and boost to 3 and leave them until you earn more psi.
- Ice mages need to max Chill. You may as well max Ice Ball and Ice Shard, the latter because it doesn't cost much psi to boost them both to 2 and more damage is useful. Like another comment said, spamming slows until they've pretty much stacked to last forever will do it, and then you would probably be better off having berserkers. No dragons allowed.
- Berserkers are good for DPS when boosted to 3; they should be used continuously after your slows have been stacked up, since no one else will be using that space directly by the road. An unboosted berserker can farm the little sheep for psi without trouble. Berserkers can be boosted over 5 if you're swimming in Psi, but they have to be frequently sold and re-placed, making it more efficient to level up your archers. Early on, sometimes I alternated Ice Mage with Berserker.
- Healers need to actually hit the sheep for Zeal to go off, I think. They need to be max level if you deploy them at all, and you have to place them so that they cover a lot of the sheep's path as well as a lot of allied squares. Any summon who is getting zealed by three healers more or less has Inspire continuously, if you look at the numbers. Good times.
- You can respec Azra to have Frenzy at 9, but I didn't bother; I'd already spent more scrap on this dumb level than I wanted to. :-/

*Some parts of the map are easier to get three Inspire buffs on your whole troop all at once than others. When you are at a good part of the map, it is better to use Frenzy then. If you're close to a point like that but not there yet, you should wait.

Whew, I'm glad that's over with. I kind of hate having to redo my whole party just to do one level... Guess I won't be getting Evni anytime soon.

**TL;DR:**

- 6 archers, 4 berserkers, 3 healers, 2 ice mages
- Always recall idle defenders
- One unboosted berserker to farm little sheep is plenty
- One archer with Bleed and Range max
- One archer with Range, Poison, and Crit max
- Other archers need Range, Crit, and Rapid Shot in some combination high as possible
- Always one-point (or more) Rapid Shot, and start archers at 3.
- Boost to 5 when possible
- Healers should always be at max or not in play at all. Try to have three casting Zeal with max Inspire at all times before too long, with most defenders getting most of the buffs. Build Healers AFTER you have your ice mages and 6 archers out, otherwise there's nothing to buff.
- Ice Mages need to max Chill. Spam slow until it's stacked indefinitely, then stop summoning these. If you misjudge the duration, just summon one next to the sheep again ASAP. Can be boosted 2 for added damage from level 9 Ice Shard, but that probably won't matter much either way. Never upgrade past 2.
- Berserkers need to be 3, with max Flurry and Madness. After healer and archer, you can upgrade these to 5 when there is extra psi and you don't have to move too many units around soon.
- Frenzy should be spammed. Level 9 is useful, but not necessary.

Comment: define TL;DR ...

Answer (score 3):

The way I did it was with 6 archers and nothing else (except for one beserker to kill the normal sheep).

The magic sheep is immune to knock back, stun, freeze, etc., so all those kinds of units are useless. Instead, go with archers (highest DPS), and reposition them when the sheep is out of range. I did it with my archers all at level 40, but I killed the sheep at 2/3 or 3/4 of the way around the circuit, so I'm sure this is also a viable strategy at lower levels.

Also, I should clarify, summon as many archers as you can initially afford, and bring more online as you accumulate PSI, which should happen fairly quickly, because you won't need to reposition your archers very often.

Good luck!

Comment: The sheep is not immune to everything because if you click on it, you can see its speed changing (from 0.04 to 0.01 I think). Although, I don't know if that is caused by a knockback or a chill effect.

Comment: erm, level 40 archers to achieve this is .. kind of difficult. I can't do it at all with 6 level 30 archers or any combination of level 30 units. Even hand repositioning them at 1/2 speed can only get the sheep down to about 500k (half) health at the end, maybe a little less. I think level 40 archers makes a big BIG difference.

Comment: What was your build for the archers? I assume that could make a pretty big difference in overall effectiveness.

Comment: In particular, focusing heavy on bleed and single-target damage skills for your archers is going to pay off a lot more than the multi-target skills, and might allow you to do it before level 40. I'm only up to level 15 or so myself so far, so haven't had a (realistic) chance to try this yet.

Comment: @sterno I have six level 30 archers and I've tried a few different builds (one in particular focusing on single target damage) with no success. I can get him down to about 350k by the time he reaches the end of the maze.

Comment: With 2 knights, 4 archers and an ice mage at around 25-30 I got it to below 100k without a good skill build. I'll try again tonight with a better skill setup and report back.

Answer (score 2):

I did this today with 6 archers ranging from 28-40 and one level 40 ice mage.  I focused on the passive archer skills including crit, bleed, and poison and focused on the ice mage skills that caused slow.  Reposition everyone as needed and boost them as much as you can.

Answer (score 2):

I did it with 6 archers between level 21-40, 2 ice mages and 4 bezerkers (all level 40).  As mentioned by others before, focus the archers on the single target traits.  The sheep only seems to be affected by some of the slow effects of the ice mages (the level 4-5 ones?), but it does make a real difference.  Use the bezerkers to follow the sheep round and only upgrade them a couple of levels, to conserve psi.

Sheep died 3 quarters of map round. :)

Answer (score 2):

I did this with 5 Zerkers (Level 20-24 with one scrap guy for the little sheep), 2 Ice Mages (Level 23ish - only need one with maxed "Chill"), 3 Knights (Level 23ish - maxed Cleave on both), 4 Archers (Level 22-24 - two max bleed, one max poison, one max crit), two healers (level 23-24 - Nothing maxed but I should have maxed Inspire).

Ice Mages go to down on the initial walkway followed by one of my Bleed archers (no reason to waste the Psi), setup a Knight on the corner when Psi is about to get full, and make sure I hit Frenzy (which I have at level 14) as soon as I have all my archers out and the sheep is in range of my Knight.

Then just setup damage as he walks along, and try to use Frenzy when Zeal is up.  Heavy focus on corners since you don't need to reposition much for them and can save Psi.  I got bored and started bombing the stupid sheep with Lightning too.  Just for giggles.

(Oh, and my Librarian is level 24, but I think she was 23 when I did this and then I leveled.)

Answer (score 1):

I just did it using some parts of each answer provided. My top level archer and berserker were both 33. So here's how I did it:

- 6 archers, always positioned to be in range of the sheep, only the 4 best were fully boosted at all times.
- 1 berserker not boosted just for killing the sheeps
- 1 ice mage (not boosted) and 1 berserker fully boosted alternating spots along the way. The ice mage had lvl 9 chill and freeze (although I'm pretty sure only chill matters)
- Lvl 9 Frenzy used as often as possible (when I didn't forget)

I did not reskill any unit, although I had focused them on passive traits for bleeding, poison and critical hits throughout my game. In the narrow path on the right, I added a second fully boosted berserker to increase my chances.

The sheep died a little bit further than half-way through.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this mentioned in any other answers, so I'd like to add that in virtually any configuration, the book "Furious Start" will help a lot in this battle.  You can get it from perfecting Challenge 2, which is in the bonus section.

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2013 you (and your guys) just have to be level 20 or so and then just rotate 3 berserkers + 2 ice mages (second row) + 2-3 rangers in the middle as the sheep goes, and it will be dead on the bottom of the screen.

Just use your mages instead of berserkers first (on the first row) when you have less energy in the beginning to slow down the sheep as much as possible.

Yes, "Furious Start" book helps a lot here, as Nuzzolilo said.

PS - I tried to find whether knights or berserkers are better for single-target DPS, but I couldn't. From my rough view, berserkers are better since they are faster and their multi-strikes are fully hitting single targets. The sheep has no armor and is immune to stun/knockback (knight's specials) but not to bleed and criticals (berserker's ones).

Answer (score 0):

Using Ice Mages works wonders. I found that using a combination of them is not good if not all of them are a high level in Chill. Somehow, the sheep only got down to 0.09 speed. With my level 6 Chill ice mage only, it got down to 0.05. 2x as much time to kill. With lvl 9 it will probably go down to 0.03 as mentioned above.

For the rest archers and berserkers. Archers should have both a decent range and a decent bow.

Then follow the sheep.

Answer (score 0):

Level 20 Librarian. Maxed out Frenzy and had the Furious Start book equipped. Nothing else that mattered. 
Character levels ranged from 18-21.
Some slight changes to the OP, seeing as how I think knights do better single target dps. I killed him a bit further than halfway down the right side.

1 berserker in the corner killing regular sheep. Boosted him once, don't think it mattered.
on the super sheep, I had a single unboosted ice mage with maxed Chill on him at all times, though not strictly necessary, as the speed debuff stacks and can last for a while after you take the ice mage away. However, I found this to be better than 3 on him for the first leg, as it allowed:
2 max boosted knights on him at all times (and 4 more waiting in the wings), with maxed Strength and all the attacks. 
I only had 5 rangers, but 6 would work better if you have the Psych for it. One had maxed Deep Shot and Range Focus to keep the bleed debuff up. All others had Sharp Shooter, Range Focus, and Rapid Shot as high as possible. Oh, and I put them further back than the OP recommended. 4-5th rows, rather than 3-4. Less moving of them was required that way, and the healers can still be placed to give everyone the Inspire buff. However,  near maxed Range Focus is required for this to work.
2 healers, with Zeal and maxed Inspire. Obviously boosted to max to get Zeal. Careful positioning will allow you to have all characters in range of Inspire.

The key to killing him as quickly as possible is to time your Frenzy to coincide with Inspire. Also, if you end up having extra Psych, don't forget that the healers will drop Zeal immediately upon getting access to it, so a good strategy is to do Frenzy right as one healer does Zeal, then unsummon him and drop and max another out right as the first Inspire wears off, maximizing time that Frenzy gets the Inspire help. Also, the Furious Start book works best when you drop knights in between uses of Frenzy, thus maximizing Frenzy time for them. Bonus points if you drop them right before a healer does Inspire, and you can use the above trick to ensure that. Pause game, drop knight, max boost him, then drop healer, max boost. And have some extra knights ready to go when the super sheep gets to the upper right. That's where he lost about 1/3 of his health in my playthrough, with 3-6 knights wacking on him.
My Psych was extremely stretched at times, but I only had one serious hick up, in the upper right "gauntlet" area. Trying to keep 6 max boosted knights on him was tough.

This isn't all necessary (other builds can kill him, if not quite as fast), but if, like me, you hate having to sit through a long fight, this seems to be the fastest way to down him. I haven't done the math, though, so berserkers might be better. I just went off the flavor text, namely that berserkers are primarily crowd killers while knights do better single target dps.